# How to detect a flash movie has finished playing with javascript / jquery and then run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I need to create a splash page type thing. It needs to play a flash movie and then when that movie has finished show a full screen image using html/js. THe movie will be flash and the image display will be javascript powered.

I have no idea how to do this on one page. Any help would be amazing.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  Example:

```
try {
ExternalInterface.call("myfunction");
} catch(e:Error) {
trace(e)
}
```

Depending on how your flash movie is constructed, when the animation reaches the last frame, running ExternalInterface.call("myfunction"); will call a function in javascript called "myfunction".  Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction()
{
   alert("hello!"); // replace with some jquery 
}
</script>
```

I can't really say how to put it into your movie, because I don't know if your movie is constructed using actionscript animation, or timeline animation, or you're wanting to play a flash video.  (If you are using a video, you can attach an event listener for Event.COMPLETE and do your c all there).  If its an actionscript animation, you'll need to find the end of a tween or something.
Wrapping it in a try/catch is just to be safe.  You'll need to make sure when you embed the swf, you have allowScriptAccess=always or sameDomain.  [Reference here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html)

Comment: Is the only way to do this by adding something inside the movie? I only have the .swf :(

I suppose i could always ask jquery to trigger a function after 5 seconds or something. But that would be a poor solution to say the least!

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but inside the flash movie you can use ExternalInterface to call javascript functions.  So, you can set up an actionscript function to run when the movie ends, and have it a call a javascript function to do whatever you need to do with the web site.

-- Disclaimer --
I don't have the cash to upgrade my Flash, so I'm still using actionscript 2.  The object I mentioned may be deprecated now - but it will still work.