# How to detect the end of an embed flash movie

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have been struggling with this problem for a some time.

Basically have no clue how to do this.

I have a simple website where I have embeded a flash movie from a different site.
I need to detect when this movie reaches its end and then do some action ...

Is this possible via jquery/js?

Thank you.
s_

Comment: Does the flashplayer you're using have some kind of JavaScript accessible API?

Comment: What player are you using?  Can you show that code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without modifying the flash movie. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4663618/1639356

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is a flash class called flash.external.ExternalInterface
AFAIK you can use that one to interface with JavaScript.
Please have a look into the details how to use it.

To get notified when a embedded flash video reaches the end I put a one-line command into the last frame on the time line:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("VideoFinished"));
```

and hook up to the movie with

```
myMovie.addEventListener("VideoFinished", myMovieFinished);
```

where myMovieFinished is the function to call. There you could place the call to utilise the ExternalInterface.